# strotime not working on different table

Tags: php

I have this code part of a table;

```
echo '<td>' . 
    $row['datum_overboeking'] = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row["datum_overboeking"])) . 
    '</td>';
```

I want to add the same piece of strtotime code to this piece of code part of another table on another page;

```
td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'datum_overboeking') . '</td>';
```

So that would be;

```
echo '<td>' . 
    mysql_result($result, $i, 'datum_overboeking') = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($row["datum_overboeking"])) . 
    '</td>';
```

But it doesnt work, it gives the error:

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/davel/www/folder1/pagina_1/view-paginated.php on line 97

Comment: You're trying to set a database resultset `mysql_result($result, $i, 'datum_overboeking'` to a date string?

Comment: Well I want the result from the database been shown in the m-d-Y format. I tought this piece of code should have done the trick but it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Baker is correct, you are trying to set a value to a MySQL result - which will error. If you wish to display the results of 'datum_overboeking' please try the following:

```
Echo '<td>'.date('m-d-Y', strtotime(mysql_result($result, $i, 'datum_overboeking')))
```

I am assuming that $row['datum_overboeking'] and mysql_result($result, $i, 'datum_overboeking') return the same kinda string and format.

Comment: Thanks and indeed that does work. I tought that the mysql_result was already a raw DATE value by default because its a DATE value from the MySQL database.